# How can I launch Java Web Start locally

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I am attempting to replace all of my Applets with Java Web Start applications.  The problem I am having is that I have not seen any examples where the codebase attribute is specified as a directory within the local file system.  I have tried setting the codebase to the directory that contains both the JNLP file and the executable JAR in each of the following ways:

```
codebase="file://users/mystuff" href=myJWS.jnlp"

codebase="http://localhost/users/mystuff" href=myJWS.jnlp"
```

When I attempt to launch the JWS app I get an application error that tells me:

```
Unable to launch application.
Component:  file://users/myStuff/myJWS.jnlp
```

OR

```
Component:  http://localhost/users/myStuff/myJWS.jnlp
Reason: Unable to load resource
```

It looks to me like I am specifying the codebase incorrectly.  Any ideas about how to fix this.

Comment: `http://localhost/users/mystuff` would only work if you are running a local HTTP server. Are you running such a server?

Comment: Did you *bother* to **read the documentation** on [Running a Java Web Start Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html)? It shows both "From a Browser" (aka remotely) and "From the Desktop" (aka locally).

Comment: Yes I did read the documentation.  Running the application from the desktop provides a simple way to launch the application.  It does not demonstrate how to specify the stand alone-application in the JNLP file.  All of the examples that I have seen always interact with some web server such as Tomcat, but I have not seen any examples that show how a stand-alone application is run.

Answer (score 2):

The local file protocol needs three forward slashes:

```
codebase="file:///F:/users/mystuff" href=myJWS.jnlp"
```

Don't forget to add the exception to the exception site list in the java console security panel. You can be as specific as you like or add the whole drive for testing:

```
file:///F:/
```